# contact form 7 does not show after update

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I had a contact form working, after updating to 4.6 (and email validation solved) it stopped working.

I created a new standard form but is not working either.

FORM:

```
<label> Nombre (requerido)
    [text* your-name] </label>

<label> Correo electrónico (requerido)
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Asunto
    [text your-subject] </label>

<label> Mensaje
    [textarea your-message] </label>

[submit "Enviar"]
```

URL: https://www.ibeernalia.com/contacto/